# Extract HTML data with different option in R

Tags: html, r

There's a really good example of this problem.

https://www.nest.co.uk/product/anglepoise-original-1227-giant-outdoor-floor-lamp

This is a product with Two options. 
One is  'Gloss Finish' type, and other one is 'Satin Finish' type.

And I can choose color with those Two types.

> - Gloss Finish - Dove Gray / Jet Black / Linen White / Alpine White / Citrus Yellow ...
> - Satin Finish - Duck Egg Blue / Blossom Pink / Linen White

And HTML are looks like these.

```
   <select title="Select an option" name="product-option"
 id="product-option-selector" class="product-option-selector">
                <option value="198841">Gloss Finish</option>
                <option value="198857">Satin Finish</option>
            </select>
```

After Select an option, There are detail data about colors.

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
                    <meta itemprop="name" content="Anglepoise Original 1227 Giant Outdoor Floor Lamp: Dove Grey" />
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="3,125.00" />
                </div><!--meta-->
```

Not like this product, others are have only one option with One product name. So there was no problem with number of row. 
I used to extract option data like below.

> 1. Extracting Options

```
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="product-option-selector"]/option')%>%
    html_text()
```

> 2. Extracting Names

```
html_nodes(".product-options")%>%
    html_nodes("[itemprop=name]")%>%
    html_attr("content")
```

But with these, There are difference about number of row, So results are like below.

```
  [Options]        [Colors]

1  Gloss Finish    Dove Gray
2  Satin Finish    Jet Black
3  NA              Linen White
4  NA              Alpine White
5  NA              Citrus Yellow
```

But I want a result like these,

```
  [Options]        [Colors]

1  Gloss Finish    Dove Gray
2  Gloss Finish    Jet Black
3  Gloss Finish    Linen White
4  Gloss Finish    Alpine White
5  Gloss Finish    Citrus Yellow
6  Satin Finish    Duck Egg Blue
7  Satin Finish    Blossom Pink
```

I tried everything I can do. I desperately need your help.
Is there any creative Idea with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- 'https://www.nest.co.uk/product/anglepoise-original-1227-giant-outdoor-floor-lamp'


page <- read_html(url) 

prods <- page %>% 
    html_nodes('#product-option-selector') %>% 
    html_nodes('option') %>% 
    map_df(~{
        id = .x %>% html_attr('value')
        name = .x %>% html_text()
        data.frame(id, name)
    })

colors <- page %>% 
    html_nodes('.option-group') %>% 
    map_df(~{
        id = .x %>% html_attr('rel')
        colors = .x %>% 
            html_nodes('li') %>% 
            html_text()
        data.frame(id, colors = colors)
    })

final <- merge(prods, colors)

# final
#        id         name           colors
# 1  198841 Gloss Finish       Dove Grey
# 2  198841 Gloss Finish       Jet Black
# 3  198841 Gloss Finish     Linen White
# 4  198841 Gloss Finish    Alpine White
# 5  198841 Gloss Finish   Citrus Yellow
# 6  198841 Gloss Finish     Crimson Red
# 7  198841 Gloss Finish    Fresh Orange
# 8  198841 Gloss Finish Vibrant Magenta
# 9  198841 Gloss Finish     Marine Blue
# 10 198857 Satin Finish   Duck Egg Blue
# 11 198857 Satin Finish    Blossom Pink
# 12 198857 Satin Finish     Linen White
# 13 198857 Satin Finish       Moon Grey
# 14 198857 Satin Finish      Slate Grey
# 15 198857 Satin Finish       Jet Black
```

It basically build two tables, just like you did, and then merge them on the ID.

Note that I chose some slightly different sources, especially for the colors name. Taking them from the `li` was simpler as string sanitation is not necessary on those.

How to build the two tables via `map_df` is quite complicated to explain, but if needed you can expand on what I gave you. (Hint: It basically perform the function inside `~{ }` for each node, and then combine in a `data.frame`)

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for late comment ! After I checked your code and I realized that you are totally genius ! I've never think that way